# Where did I make my mistake in calculating this error function antiderivative?

Tags: calculus

I am relatively new to calculus and higher mathematics (1 year), and I'm trying to learn it and get a head-start before my high-school class introduces it, plus I have a general interest anyway.

The integral I'm trying to solve is $\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$. I started with a u-sub for the exponent, ending up with $u = -\frac{x^2}{2}$, to prepare for differentiation I rewrote this as $-1(\frac{1}{2}x^2)$. Differentiating both sides I got $du = -1(\frac{1}{2}2x)dx = -xdx$, dividing both sides by the $-x$ to isolate the $dx$, I got $dx = -\frac{du}{x}$. Then I solved the u integral I got which is very easy, $\frac{\int e^u du}{-x}$ which equals $-\frac{e^u}{x}$, unsubbing the u, I got $-\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{x}$, which after simplifying is $-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{e^{x^2}}} + C$, which is different from WolframAlpha's answer: $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}(erf(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})) + C$, and completely different. I double-checked what I wrote and everything looks ok, any tips?

Comment: You need to substitute for $x.$ Here $x=\pm\sqrt{-2u}.$ You can't treat $x$ as a constant in the integral after the substitution.

Comment: Everything exists inside the integral, but you pulled the $x$ piece from $u$ sub out of the integral. It needs to be converted to an expression involving $u$.

Comment: What if you tried the substitution $u=x^2/2$ for $$\int\frac{x^2}2\,dx?$$ You'd get $$\frac1x\int u\,du=\frac{u^2}{2x}=\frac{x^3}{8},$$ when the real integral would be $\frac{x^3}{6}.$

Comment: If, on the other hand, you replace $dx$ with $\frac{du}{\sqrt{2u}},$ you get the integral is $$\frac2{3\sqrt2}u^{3/2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}\frac{x^3}{2^{3/2}}=\frac{x^3}6,$$ the result we'd expect.

Comment: While in this simple case, we can get a closed form,  in your original, the $\sqrt{-2u}$ in the denominator makes the integral intractable. You are now trying to integrate $e^u/\sqrt{-2u},$ which is not any easier that the orginal

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Intractable? $±\sqrt{-2u}$ is equal to $±i\sqrt{2u}$ which when you put in the fraction it comes from ends up with a result with a complex number, so would this be considered "not valid" and have to be replaced by some arbitrary "error function" to make sense? This is all speculation, I might have this completely wrong.

Comment: If $u$ is non-positive, which is true for $u=-x^2/2,$ there is no reason to go to complex numbers to write $\sqrt{-2u}.$ It is just $\sqrt{2|u|}.$  @AshtonDowling